# VB6 MSXML2 DOMDocument .xml Property appends NewLine character

Tags: xml, vb6, msxml

I have a legacy VB 6 application to maintain which uses msxml4.dll.

It uses the .loadXML Method of MSXML2.DOMDocument to create from xml strings and then uses the .xml Property to output strings of xml:

```
Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")
Call doc.loadXML("<doc/>")

' ... manipulation of doc ...

Dim xml As String
xml = doc.xml
```

I have discovered an issue with the .xml Property. When using the above code the string xml has a NewLine at the end:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

If it can't be stopped (i.e. if it's a bug in MSXML or by design) then how can I remove it in VB 6? `Trim(xml)` doesn't work

**EDIT** I have updated the question as it it the .xml Property not the .loadXML Method which appears to be at fault. If I select the doc as an Element:

```
Dim elm As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Set elm = doc.selectSingleNode("doc")
xml = elm.xml
```

then the .xml Property acts as expected with no added NewLine character, so it appears it is specific to the DOMDocument.xml Property.

**EDIT 2:** Following SpectralGhost's answer, here is what I ended up using:

```
If Right(xml, Len(vbNewLine)) = vbNewLine Then
    xml = Left(xml, Len(xml) - Len(vbNewLine))
End If
```

I use vbNewLine to avoid platform specific issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it worked.

```
IF RIGHT(xml,2)=vbCrLf THEN
   xml=LEFT(xml,LEN(xml)-2)
END IF
```

Comment: Yep, that was one of my options. I ended up going with `xml = Replace(xml, vbNewLine, "")`

Comment: I didn't go that route in the event that there was a newline somewhere else in the string.

Comment: Indeed, I discovered the same when I was applying this change across the rest of the codebase - I've updated my Q with a formatted version of what I went with in the end!

Answer (score 0):

XML itself ignores/collapses whitespace so it isn't a problem for the parser. If you really want to get rid of the trailing CRLF, you could try setting `doc.preserveWhiteSpace = true`.

Comment: `preserveWhiteSpace = true` has no effect - the crlf is still there. AIUI preserveWhiteSpace only refers to the whitespace in what is being loaded (in this case there is none in the `"<doc/>"` string), not the ouput.